# How to force persistent privacy & security best practice settings on Windows

Tags: antivirus, powershell, windows-permissions, cmd

Some of you might know [privacy.sexy](https://privacy.sexy). It gives you plenty of options regarding your Windows privacy and security settings. However, after a major Windows update, those settings will be reset by Windows.

I developed some code to keep my settings persistent even after those updates. For now I started by creating a Service DLL and persisting this into the svchost.

In this regard, I have two questions:

- When running the batch file from privacy.sexy, Bitdefender is blocking the cmd execution. I can exclude it from Bitdefender, but is there another way than creating an official program to get it trusted by Antivirus programs? (Was thinking about Antivirus evasion, but that wouldn't be a reliable approach)
- Will the Service DLL also be detected and blocked by antivirus programs?

Comment: What an AV will detect is entirely up to the specific AV. Ultimately, you need to test.

Comment: Indeed, thats what I thought. So the only way would be to create some antivirus evasion, testing it for all Antiviruses and changing it as soon as some antivirus tools are detecting it. Or simply tell the users what to exclude exactly. 

Thank you for the answer. Was not sure if I did miss anything. Will make the project open source as soon as it is in a ok-ish state.

Comment: Why test against all AV? Just test against the one you are using (Bitdefender).

Comment: Because I thought about making it open source for all who want to have a solution for the known problem as well.

Comment: Wait, you want to create a DLL, add it to svchost, and make it open source for others to use? I'm afraid you won't get a lot of takers for that.

Comment: Your question is "how do I make a DLL so that it can be trusted by Windows and AV products?" That's an answered question.

Comment: Not exactly. More like a tool to create a DLL based on what options you want to get from the privacy.sexy tool.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/229569/as-a-software-industry-editor-how-to-avoid-my-software-being-quarantined

Comment: Is it possible you can do something similar using Group Policy or something that actually does properly persist?

Comment: Group Policy is definitely the best, supported solution for this. Why reinvent the wheel?